# "Do" in Simple Present Tense in British Style

Tags: sentence-structure, present-simple

In British english, I know simple present tense allows do/does like,

> I **do** follow the rules,

or

> He **does** follow the rules.

My question is about whether all action verb follow this rule like:

> I *do* eat rice;
>   I *do* go to school

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That use is called "emphatic form"

According to [the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/do)

> We use do, does (present simple) or did (past simple) to give extra
>   force to the main verb. We use the infinitive of the main verb without
>   to, and stress do/does/did when speaking.

There are minor exceptions like other auxiliary verbs like **be** or **have**. You can find additional information about these exceptions [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78549/can-be-be-used-with-the-modal-verb-do?rq=1)

Comment: It's also not limited to action verbs. Catenative verbs and linking verbs can also use 'do' - "you do look pale", "you do force people to think", "you do remember to show off".

Comment: Also, good read [here:](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode119/languagepoint.shtml)

Comment: If linking verbs can take 'do' how will you use it(do) in the sentence like, "I am a student? @SamBC

Comment: I did mention that *be* is an exception to the use of *do* for emphasis. *Am* is a form of *be*, so you can't use it in that way in that student. Spoken aloud, you would just emphasise *am*. If you had to do it in writing, there are several options depending on register.